# Can you explain what (~ not bit-wise) do?

Tags: bitwise-operators

```
function test($n){
return (~ $n ** 1 / 2)**2;
}
```

if `$n = 5`
the output will be `9`. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bitwise not operator `~` simply flips every bit in the given number, zeros become ones and ones become zeros. In this case, you have that `$n` is 5, which, in binary, is `101`. However, as you surely know, numbers in a computer have a fixed bit size; most times it's something like 32 bits, but lets say for this case we have 8-bit numbers. Then 5 would actually be `0000 0101`. Now, if you apply the `~` operator on this number, you get `1111 0101`. That number, as it is, is 245 in decimal notation. However, most likely you are working with signed integers, which means that numbers with the first bit set to `1` are actually negative, according to the [two's complement convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). The general rule is quite simple: given a number *n*, applying a bitwise not operation gives you -*n* - 1 (independently of the bit size). This means that in this case we would get a -6. So the final result, taking into account the operator precedence, would be:

```
((((~5) ** 1) / 2) ** 2) = ((((-6) ** 1) / 2) ** 2) = ((-3) ** 2) = 9
```